# how to select all with to_char function in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

the code below is my sqlcommand for select statement. Inside have a lots of data including two date data inside.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TASKMASTER WHERE TASKNAME ='" + TaskName + "'";
```

can I add in `('DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')AS CREATEDATE` into the sqlcommand and at the same time will call out all the column in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a table **alias**.

For example,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t.dt_column, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as CREATEDATE, 
       t.* 
FROM TASKMASTER t 
WHERE t.TASKNAME = '" + TaskName + "'"
```

So, you added your desired column in the beginning of the column list, and also selecting all other columns followed by it.